# Jasmine angular - mocking http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, http, jasmine

I've just read a lot of articles about mocking $http and something is wrong with my code. I still have error: **No pending request to flush** !

My method from controllers.js looks similar to this (browserDebugMode, webRoot, commentsAction are global variables - it wasn't mi idea to make it global :D)

```
$scope.getComments = function(){   
        if (browserDebugMode) {
            $http({
                method  : "GET",
                url     : webRoot+commentsAction,
                params  : {action: "list"},
            })
                .success(function(data, status) {
                    //...
                })
                .error(function(data, status) {
                   //...
                });     
        } 
}
```

And now test for it:

```
var browserDebugMode = true;
var webRoot = "http://localhost/name";
var commentsAction = '/commentsMobile.php';

describe('myApp', function() {
var scope,
    httpBackend,
    http,
    controller;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

describe('NewsDetailCtrl', function() {

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $http) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        http = $http;
        httpBackend.when("GET", webRoot+commentsAction).respond([{}]);
        controller = $controller('NewsDetailCtrl', {
            '$scope': scope, 'GlobalService': globalService, $http: $http
        });
    }));

    it('checks if AJAX is done', function () {
        httpBackend.expectGET(webRoot+commentsAction).respond([{}]);
        scope.getComments()
        httpBackend.flush();
    });
  });

});
```

And please don't ask for PHP script :) I was pushed to do it.

I just want to check if I can test $http, nothing more. I don't know what I do wrong. I tested other things in that controller and it was okay, I looked if getComments() is fired with console.log and it's fired. Something must be wrong with configuring it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code under test and the unit tests execute in different contexts, so they will have different global objects and therefore the `browserDebugMode` that exists in your tests is different to the one in your actual code.

The controller should inject `$window` (Angular's wrapper around the `window` object) and then check the `browserDebugMode` property of that:

```
if ($window.browserDebugMode) {
    // actual code
}
```

The tests should also inject `$window` and then set the `browserDebugMode` property of that:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($window) {
    $window.browserDebugMode = true;
}));
```

Now both the controller and tests will reference the same global object, the `if` condition should evaluate true, and the `$http` call should execute.